# Cookies are not deleted in Google Chrome if use yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I use framework Yii2. When i make:

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 60);//cookies for 60 seconds
```

Browser Google Chrome does not remove cookies after the expiration of 60 seconds.

---

If I do not use a framework Yii2:

```
setcookie("test", time() + (60), "/");
```

it all works.

---

Why, if you use Yii2, that does not work delete cookies in browser GoogleChrom?

Comment: do you have `enableSession = false` ?

Comment: @Jorgen I have :  `'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [ 
                'name' => '_identity',
                'httpOnly' => false,
            ],`

Comment: @Jorgen i not have `enableSession = false`

Comment: @Jorgen Where should I set this - `enableSession = false` ?

Comment: You should't :) that would make Yii ignore the $duration-variable

Comment: @Jorgen Please, show Example.

Comment: I'm still looking into it, the `enableSession`was just a question, you have it correctly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Yii::$app->user->login($user, $duration);` only sets the time the _identity-cookie is alive if the browser is closed.

To log someone out after a set time of inactivity you have to set duration to `null` and add `'authTimeout' => 60` in the user component.

*common\models\LoginForm.php*

```
...
return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), null);
...
```

*frontend\config\main.php*

```
...
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 60,
    ],
...
```

Yii2 comes with great documentation, I advice having a look:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: Very Very Big Thanks! But i can't read cookies : `$cotest3 = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('_identity');`

Comment: the _identity-cookie is for keeping a user logged in on browser closing. What information do you need? It's accessible in `Yii::$app->user->identity`

Comment: I want read information for Cookies `'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',` But i can't read information for cookies

Comment: This information is not stored in a cookie. You can access the information with the `Yii::$app->user->identity` class. Example getId() and getAuthKey(). Password is not stored in plain text, and shouldn't be.

Comment: Why you specify duration to `null` in `return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), null);` ?   So, too, is working -  `return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 30);`

Comment: Maybe better to use? Example: `return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 60);` and `'authTimeout' => 60,`

Comment: That would make it possible to close the browser and still be logged in if you open the browser within 60 sec. Sure :) have a nice one.